# Informations about processes/windows inside VMware

Tags: winapi, memory, windows-7, virtual-machine, vmware

I was wondering if it is possible to gather information about a running virtualized system (e.g. enumerating processes, finding window captions, window positions on a windows system).
My naive approach was using ReadProcessMemory() on vmware-vmx.exe and searching for data structures like _tagWND. This didn't work out as expected. :/
I don't want to "touch" the guest system if I don't have to.

So, how could I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

There are APIs to talk to the VMware Tools inside the guest. See the VMware VIX API [here](http://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vix-api/).

In the [list of common tasks](http://www.vmware.com/products/beta/vmware_server/vix_api/ReferenceGuide/tasks.html#0_80487) from the documentation, there are the following guest operations that would probably do what you're after:

```
VixVM_ListProcessesInGuest()
VixVM_RunProgramInGuest()
VixVM_RunScriptInGuest()
```